# ID from gridview in label

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which there is ID column.. now when i click on that column then i want to display that ID in label

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        ID = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

        Label1.Text = "<b>Publisher Name  &nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;   " + ID + "</b>";

    }
```

when i click on ID label display `publisher name` but i want to display ID from grid view

HOW I DO THAT

Comment: Do you want it on `click` event or on `RowDataBound` event

Comment: on click .. when i click on gridview row

Comment: So do you have the `click` event in your code

Comment: no.. i want when i click on row..

Comment: i think u should use gridview row command event to accomplish this task

Comment: no.. i don't select button in grid view i just want when i click on grid view row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong event.You should enable row selection in your `GridView` through `AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"` and handle the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class GridViewSelectionExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Bind();
        }
    }

    private void Bind()
    {
        User user1 = new User { ID = 1, Name = "User 1" };
        User user2 = new User { ID = 2, Name = "User 2" };
        User user3 = new User { ID = 3, Name = "User 3" };

        GridView1.DataSource = new List<User> { user1, user2, user3 };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        lblCurrentID.Text = String.Format("The selected id is - {0}", id);
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblCurrentID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```